# Fastest way to parse thousands of small files in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have over 16000 inventory log files ranging in size from 3-5 KB on a network share.
Sample file looks like this:

```
## System Info
SystemManufacturer:=:Dell Inc.                
SystemModel:=:OptiPlex GX620               
SystemType:=:X86-based PC
ChassisType:=:6 (Mini Tower)

## System Type
isLaptop=No
```

I need to put them into a DB, so I started parsing them and creating a custom object for each that I can later use to check duplicates, normalize etc...

Initial parse with a code snippet as in below took about 7.5mins.

```
Foreach ($invlog in $invlogs) {
    $content = gc $invlog.FullName -ReadCount 0
    foreach ($line in $content) {
        if ($line -match '^#|^\s*$') { continue }
        $invitem,$value=$line -split ':=:'
        [PSCustomObject]@{Name=$invitem;Value=$value}
    }
}
```

I started optimizing it and after several trial and error ended up with this which takes 2mins and 4 secs:

```
 Foreach ($invlog in $invlogs) {
        foreach ($line in ([System.IO.File]::ReadLines("$($invlog.FullName)") -match '^\w')  ) {
           $invitem,$value=$line -split ':=:'
           [PSCustomObject]@{name=$invitem;Value=$value}  #2.04mins
        }
    }
```

I also tried using a hash instead of PSCustomObject, but to my surprise it took much longer (5mins 26secs)

```
       Foreach ($invlog in $invlogs) {                        
        $hash=@{}        
        foreach ($line in ([System.IO.File]::ReadLines("$($invlog.FullName)") -match $propertyline)  ) {

           $invitem,$value=$line -split ':=:'
           $hash[$invitem]=$value #5.26mins
        }
    }
```

What would be the fastest method to use here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this is any faster:

```
Foreach ($invlog in $invlogs) {
@(gc $invlog.FullName -ReadCount 0) -notmatch '^#|^\s*$' |
 foreach {
          $invitem,$value=$line -split ':=:'
          [PSCustomObject]@{Name=$invitem;Value=$value}
         }
}
```

The -match and -notmatch operators, when appied to an array return all the elements that satisfy the match, so you can eliminate having to test every line for the lines to exclude.

Are you really wanting to create a PS Object for every line, or just one for every file?

If you want one object per file, see if this is any quicker:
The multi-line regex eliminates the line array, and a filter is used in place of the foreach to create the hash entries.

```
 $regex = [regex]'(?ms)^(\w+):=:([^\r]+)'
 filter make-hash { @{$_.groups[1].value = $_.groups[2].value} }

Foreach ($invlog in $invlogs) {
$regex.matches([io.file]::ReadAllText($invlog.fullname)) | make-hash
 }
```

The objective of switching to using the multi-line regex and [io.file]::ReadAllText] is to simplify what Powershell is doing with the file input internally.  The result of [io.file]::ReadAllText() will be a string object, which is a much simpler type of object than the array of strings that [io.file]::ReadAllLines() will produce, and requires less overhead to counstruct internally.  A filter is essentially just the Process block of a function - it will run once for every object that comes to it from the pipeline, so it emulates the action of foreach-object, but actually runs slightly faster (I don't know the internals well enough to tell you exactly why).  Both of these changes require more coding and only result in a marginal increase in performace.  In my testing switching to multi-line gained about .1ms per file, and changing from foreach-object to the filter another .1 ms.  You probably don't see these techniques used very often because of the low return compared to the additional coding work required, but it becomes significant when you start to multiply those fractions of a ms by 160K iterations.

Comment: 3mins and 9secs. I initially had the regex that way but changed it to '\w' to test, and it was faster that way. Was not sure why.

Comment: This is 2 mins 30 secs:
 foreach ($line in ([System.IO.File]::ReadLines("$($invlog.FullName)") -notmatch '^##|^\s*$')  ) {
               $invitem,$value=$line -split ':=:';[PSCustomObject]@{name=$invitem;Value=$value}  
            }

Comment: Do you have remoting enabled on the server where this share is located?

Comment: It does not look so. Server guys did not discover powershell yet.

Comment: You can probably shave some more time off if you run it locally.

Comment: True, but not an option unfortunately. I also tried using jobs but it seems that the overhead actually makes it much worse than 7.5 milisecond / file  I am at right now.

Comment: Added another option, using a multi-line regex to extract the data.

Comment: Eventually, I would want one object per file. The technique I am using,as @msorens calls it "amalgamation" of those per line objects gives me what I need at the end.

Comment: As for results,initially multi-line regex came out to be slower: 5mins 43secs. But I ran it again a few mins later and this time it was 1mins 37secs. That must be b/c of filesystem caching. So, I ran the fastest solution I had before (2.04mins )to compare and that resulted in 2.21mins. So, yes your solution is officially the fastest one. Thank you! I get what (?ms) and filter are doing but Could you please add a bit more explanation to why you used these techniques, which are not that common, for everyone's benefit?

Comment: I already marked your response as the answer but I am continuing to compare them by making sure file system caching is not skewing the results. The one I posted seems to bounce between 2mins and 2.30mins, while multi-regex has a wider range and slower without caching...

Comment: Done.  Need to take this to chat if you want to discuss further.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Foreach ($invlog in $invlogs) {
    $output = @{}
    foreach ($line in ([IO.File]::ReadLines("$($invlog.FullName)") -ne '')  ) {
        if ($line.Contains(":=:")) {
            $item, $value = $line.Split(":=:") -ne '' 
            $output[$item] = $value
        }        

    }

    New-Object PSObject -Property $output
}
```

As a general rule, Regex is sometimes cool but always slower.

Comment: Thanks for your input, it's good to know! I got 6mins 5secs on this though. Do you think it can be improved further?

Comment: I actually have a script that I recently built for a similar purpose that uses filestreams.  This is a lot faster if you only want the first few lines, since it avoids reading the whole file.  Please get in touch to get the script.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you want an object per system, and not per key-value pair? :S
Like this.. By replacing `Get-Content` to the .Net method you could probably save some time.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt -Path <path to files> | ForEach-Object {

    $ht = @{}

    Get-Content $_ | Where-Object { $_ -match ':=:' } | ForEach-Object {

        $ht[($_ -split ':=:')[0].Trim()] = ($_ -split ':=:')[1].Trim()

    }

    [pscustomobject]$ht

}

ChassisType                          SystemManufacturer                   SystemType                          SystemModel
-----------                          ------------------                   ----------                          -----------
6 (Mini Tower)                       Dell Inc.                            X86-based PC                        OptiPlex GX620
```

Comment: That is similar to my hash attempt, but you have additional pipelines which is making it much slower: 8mins 18 secs.

Comment: Also, yes, you are right about my intention and assigning hash back to CustomObject, yet I know how to partition it for each computer. The part I am interested in is increasing the performance of reading the file and processing them.

Comment: You're right. The idea was to save time by delaying object creation until the machine was completely scanned, as creating objects takes some time. But to be honest with you. If performance is that important for you, you should write a console app, not use powershell. powershell has a lot of overhead.